# How to equalize hash creation speed across different processors?

Tags: hash, gpu, cpu, blockchain

I wondered a time ago why no technology exists to equalize the hash creation speed across different cpu's/gpu's. I have no idea if this is feasible or not, that's why I ask this question here. The idea behind this is to make the proof of work just between two parties with each a 50% chance to create the winning hash (equal hashing speed!). In combination with an easier to find nonce, this solution is energy friendlier than existing proof of work technologies, while the desired goal is still met.

Comment: It seems that you want to make all hash calculations to take as long as the slowest processor? Does that make sense?

Comment: Or even slower!

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less impossible for the simple reason that a faster machine is just … faster. If one of the two parties buys a faster machine, then they will compute the hash faster. That's just the way it is.

However, there is *something* we can do. Bitcoin, for example, is based on SHA-256 (the 256 bit long version of SHA-2). SHA-2 is *specifically* designed to be fast, and to be easy to speed up by specialized hardware. And that is exactly what we see happen in the Bitcoin mining space with the move from pure software-based mining to CPUs with built-in acceleration for SHA-2 to GPUs to FPGAs to ASICs.

The reason for this is that SHA-2 is designed as a general cryptographic hash function, and one of the main usage of cryptographic hashes is as the basis for TLS/SSL and digital signatures where large amounts of data need to be hashed in a short amount of time.

But, there are other use cases for cryptographic hash functions, in particular, password hashing. For password hashing, we want the hash function to be *slow* and *hard to speed up*, since a *legitimate* user only needs to hash a very small amount of data (the password) once (when logging in), whereas an attacker needs to hash large numbers of passwords over and over again, for a brute force attack.

Examples for such hash functions are PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt, Catena, Lyra2, yescrypt, Makwa, and Argon2 (the latter being the winner of the 2013 Password Hashing Competition). Scrypt in particular is designed to be hard to speed up using GPUs, FPGAs, and ASICs as well as through space-time or time-space tradeoffs. Scrypt uses a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator to initialize a huge array of pseudo-random numbers in memory, and then uses another CSPRNG to generate indices for accesses into this array, thus making both the memory contents as well as the memory access patterns pseudo-random.

Theoretically, of course, it would be possible to pre-compute the result, after all, accessing an array in some specific order is the same as accessing a much larger array in linear order, however, scrypt is designed in such a way that this pre-computed array would be prohibitively large. Plus, scrypt has a simple work-factor parameter that can be used to exponentially increase the size of this array, if memory capacity increases. So, trading space for time is not possible.

Likewise, it would be possible to create a PRNG which combines the two pseudo-random processes into one process and computes the results on the fly. However, scrypt is designed in such a way that the computing time for this would be prohibitively long, and again, there is the exponential work-factor which can be used to drastically increase the computing time without changes to the algorithm. So, trading time for space is not possible.

The pseudo-random access pattern to the memory also defeats any sort of branch-prediction, memory prefetching or caching scheme of the CPU.

And lastly, since the large array is a shared global mutable state, and there is no way to sensibly divide the work into independent units, the algorithm is not sensibly parallelizable, which means you can't speed it up using GPUs.

And in fact, some newer cryptocurrencies, smart contracts, blockchains etc. use an scrypt-based proof-of-work scheme.

Note, however, that running scrypt on a faster machine is still faster than running scrypt on a slower machine. There is no way around that. It just means that we cannot get the *ridiculous* amounts of speedup we get from using specialized hardware for SHA-2, for example. But, designing cryptographic algorithms is *hard*, and there actually *are* ASIC-based scrypt miners for Litecoin out there, that *do* get a significant speedup, however still less than the impressive ones we see for SHA-2 / Bitcoin.

Comment: So the answer is that the hash time is controlled by the hardware and there is no solution to equalize hash times across hardware.

Comment: Although your explanation is way above my capabilities, I was more thinking of a built-in time slice to compute one hash. A time slice that has a fixed amount of time spanning the capabilities of most modern processors.

Comment: @NicoVerrijdt The problem with a time slice it that it will be gamed, that is miners will figure out how to defeat it. Either mod the code or if time slices run more instances. This is the same problem we have with password hashes, we would love a method that would always, on all processors, require ~100ms. The best we can do is require an iteration count but need to accommodate slow processors and attackers may have a hundred GPUs. Argon2 helps in that is required substantial memory as well as computation.

Comment: @NicoVerrijdt: Are you talking about simply putting the CPU to sleep or executing NOPs? If that is what you mean, then the attacker will just remove the code which implements the sleep from the mining software.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That is why iteration is the key, it can not be short-circuited, but that does not help with the speed difference between devices/computers.